# Get connection string inside TimerJob

Tags: web-config

Is it possible to get connection string from web.config inside TimerJob?

Comment: What are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have procedure that will read web.config keys inside Timer Job:

- [Sharepoint Timerjob: Read the web.config inside a Timer Job](http://knrs.blogspot.com/2008/01/sharepoint-read-webconfig-inside-timer.html)

For future readers: Be sure that you also read comment written by @Wictor (!)

Comment: I recommend not to store any configuration needed in SharePoint in the web.config. Use other alternatives such as the property bags (see SharePoint Patterns & Practices hierarchical config for instance)